# Make on windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I am trying to run the make command on windows 10. Downloaded the make setup from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) and installed it on my system.

I am trying to compile the [git-subrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) library but not able to do so.

I get the following error

```
> make

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which git, ...) failed.
makefile:3: *** 'git' is not installed on this system.  Stop.
```

Git is installed on the system.

```
> git --version

git version 2.17.0.windows.1
```

I have never used make before. Sorry, if this is a silly thing I am asking.

Comment: That is a super-old version of GNU make (3.81 was released in 2006) but I have no idea if that's your problem or not.  I'm assuming if you run `which git` from the prompt, like the makefile does, that it works?  If so, somehow the PATH that make is using is different than the PATH that your prompt is using, so that the former cannot find Git.

Comment: @MadScientist Yea seems like a problem with "which" itself. Windows has a "where" command instead. Would you suggest any other way to run make on windows.

Comment: If you're trying to build some software you should use whatever method they suggest.  Note that not all source code can be easily built on all systems.  If the software wasn't written to be portable it can be a big effort to compile it on a different system (e.g., if it was written for POSIX systems like Linux or MacOS, it might be hard to build on Windows).  You should check the documentation for the software you're trying to build and see how they recommend to build it.

Comment: A quick look at that repo and it seems that the utility is written in Perl and doesn't require compilation, and the makefile is just there to help install.  So you don't really need the makefile, you could just invoke the install steps by hand.  You should ask for help from that project; maybe they can point you to documentation for this or help you create some new documentation for other Windows users.